# How can I customize the Icons of react-jinke-music-player

Tags: reactjs

I am using an audio player package named react-jinke-music-player, I want to customize the icons of this package. If any one used this package please, share your thoughts.

Here is the package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jinke-music-player

---

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lijinke666/react-music-player#bulb-customize-player-icon

```
<ReactJkMusicPlayer icon={{ play: <IconA/>, pause: <IconB/> }}/>
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanations for your answer.